# Does QString has a limit size on UWP Kit

Tags: c++, qt, uwp, windows-runtime

I fill a bugreport about QString holding data over 11KB. It just crashed my application and it only happen on UWP kit aka WinRT. Any idea on how to get around of it until the Qt Team resolved it ?

To reproduce the crash, create an application based on Qt Quick 2 template, copy paste a string of 11KB on the textfield then clic the button.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61911

Comment: Do not pass `QString` to `qDebug`?

Comment: I don't really get your question. I can easily reproduce the crash by assigning a QString object a data of 11KB without even to qdebug() it

Comment: Then why bug report's title says "passing a QString of a certain size on qDebug() crashed on UWP"? It is unclear what the bug is. Are you even sure there is a bug?This is a C++ after all, people misuse code all the time. Maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: the bug is that if you want to use QString object to hold data of certain size, whatever how did you get this data (restful, direct input from the user on a textfield, etc...), it crashes the program. and it only happen on UWP.